# Copy/backup all dirs containing files matching a regexp

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, backup, rsync

I would like to do a backup where I recursively go through a dir structure and only get directories with files whose names matching a particular regexp. I would like to keep the directory structure, so that if there is a match at

~/dir1/dir2/regexpmatch.txt

it creates the same dir structure in the target and the file is copied over to

/media/backup/dir1/dir2/regexpmatch.txt

preferably with rsync, but if that is not possible another program would do.

Answer (score 1):

How about combining `find` with `tar`? An example to find all `.c` files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -print | tar zcf backup.tar.gz -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

You should combine `find` and `rsync` commands this way:

```
find . -regex .*X | rsync --files-from=- ./ b/
```

Example of usage:

```
$ find b/
b/
b/a
b/a/dX
b/a/cX
$ find a/
a/
a/dX
a/cX
a/b
$ rm -rf b
$ find . -regex .*X | rsync --files-from=- ./ b/
$ find b/
b/
b/a
b/a/dX
b/a/cX
```

Here I copy only that files that are conform to the regular expression `.*X`.

Answer (score -1):

From the rsync man page:

```
Here s  an  example that copies all .pdf files in a hierarchy, only creating
the necessary destination directories to hold the .pdf  files,  and  ensures
that  any  superfluous  files and directories in the destination are removed
(note the hide filter of non-directories being used instead of an exclude):

rsync -avm --del --include= *.pdf  -f  hide,! */  src/ dest

If you didn t want to remove superfluous destination files, the  more  time-
honored  options  of "--include= */  --exclude= * " would work fine in place
of the hide-filter (if that is more natural to you).
```